# kivy error when adding the navigationbar in matplotlib : It already has a parent

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

Dears,
I want to display some matplotlib graphs and their matplotlib toolbars in a Kivy frame.

When  the line `g.graf1.add_widget(n.actionbar)` is commented, the matplotlib graph is displayed as expected.

When uncommented, I got the error `kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add <kivy.uix.actionbar.ActionSeparator object at 0x000001EC7BB1EE18>, it already has a parent <kivy.uix.actionbar.ActionOverflow object at 0x000001EC7BB1E590>`

Running Python 3.6.3, Matplotlib 2.1.1, Kivy v1.10.0 on Windows 10.
Here is the python and kivy code to reproduce error.
Thks for your help.
Rgds

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('module://kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivy')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvas,\
                                                NavigationToolbar2Kivy
#create kick matplotlib grah
f=plt.figure()
topGraph=plt.subplot2grid((3,3),(0,0), rowspan=2, colspan=3)
topGraph.plot([1,2,3], [34,22,36], 'go-', label='line 1', linewidth=2)
canvas = f.canvas

class HelloWorldApp(App):
    def build(self):
        g=MyMatApp()
        n = NavigationToolbar2Kivy(canvas)
        g.graf1.add_widget(canvas)
        g.graf1.add_widget(n.actionbar) #---- ERROR it already has a parent
        return g

class MyMatApp(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyMatApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        grid = ObjectProperty(None)
        graf1 = ObjectProperty(None)
        graf2 = ObjectProperty(None)

if __name__=='__main__':
    HelloWorldApp().run()
```

.KV

```
<MyMatApp>:
    grid: Grid
    graf1: Graphe1
    graf2: Graphe2
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            BoxLayout:
                id : Graphe1
                orientation: 'vertical'
            Button: 
                text: 'Middle'
            BoxLayout:
                id : Graphe2
                orientation: 'vertical'

        GridLayout:
            id: Grid
            cols: 5
            rows: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have this answered by now but i just recently experienced a similar issue and I decided to full on just get the buttons out of the action view and place them as i please in my layout. Just remember that the button have to be removed from their current parent widget to be added to another widget. Hope this helps.

```
grid = GridLayout(cols=9)
i=0
while i < 9:
    kid = nav.actionbar.children[0].children[0]
    nav.actionbar.children[0].remove_widget(kid)
    grid.add_widget(kid)
    i+=1
mainNav.add_widget(grid)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, `NavigationToolbar2Kivy`, only work on father layout 
Example:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvas,\
                                                NavigationToolbar2Kivy
self.menu=BoxLayout()
self.grid=GridLayout()
self.menu.add_widget(self.grid)
#Graph is a graphic example, like bar, plot or hist<br>
Canvas=FigureCanvasKivyAgg(graph) 
self.grid.add_widget(Canvas)`<br>
toolbar=NavigationToolbar2Kivy(Canvas)
#Well, my father layout is self.menu and isn't self.grid, then...
self.menu.add_widget(toolbar.actionbar)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: format your code with


\`\`\`py


code();


\`\`\`


so that it's easier to read

Comment: I don't know how to use, can you explain me please?