# navigationtoolbar2kivy not rendered proper

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

It seems the code work properly, I'm sure. But the results not, here's the code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg as FC
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import NavigationToolbar2Kivy as NT

class APP(App):
    def build(self):
        self.menu = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.grid = GridLayout(cols=1)
        self.menu.add_widget(self.grid)

        graphic1 = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        a = graphic1.add_subplot(111)
        a.hist([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 12, 123, 3, 2, 1, 2, 34, 43, 2, 1, 1])

        # Create a Matplotlib canvas
        canvas = FC(graphic1)
        self.grid.add_widget(canvas)

        # Create the navigation toolbar and associate it with the canvas
        toolbar = NT(canvas)
        self.menu.add_widget(toolbar.actionbar)

        return self.menu

APP().run()
```

and this the result i got:

[image: the black box on bottom is should be the navigation toolbar, thanks for helping me]

I've read the documentation provided by kivy-garden, read the source code from github, copy paste some similar case, using chatgpt, and its not working. thanks for your help

The problem is, the blackbox on bottom should be the navigationtoolbar, but it's not shown properly.

Comment: You must add the reference when using other SO answers or questions. As such, it seem like this came from [kivy error when adding the navigationbar in matplotlib : It already has a parent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70856641/7758804)

Comment: Try this [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSswD.png)

Comment: well, every modified code i try seems not working. i'll try on other machine, maybe its rendering problem